# How to change legend title according to different selected values

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

Working on an interactive bubble graph plot, in which the user can select different variables to map onto the bubble color aesthetic. I'm trying to make the legend label associated with bubble color more readable with the following code, but have not been successful. Any help is much appreciated!

```
 p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = .data[[input$x_axis]], y = .data[[input$y_axis]],
                               size = .data[[input$bubble_size]], 
                               text = label)) +
      geom_point(aes(alpha = 0.2, colour = .data[[input$bubble_color]])) +

[OTHER CODE]

      labs(
        if (input$bubble_color == "total_spending_from_all_known_sources"){
               colour = "All-Reported Spending"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "total_spending_from_all_known_sources_per_child"){
               colour = "All-Reported Spending per Child"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "total_state_and_tanf_spending"){
               colour = "State Spending"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "state_tanf_per_child_spending"){
               colour = "State Spending per Child"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "three_year_olds_pct"){
               colour = "Percent of 3-Year-Olds Enrolled"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "four_year_olds_pct"){
               colour = "Percent of 4-Year-Olds Enrolled"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "x3s_4s_pct"){
               colour = "Percent of 3- & 4-Year-Olds Enrolled"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "three_year_olds"){
               colour = "Number of 3-Year-Olds Enrolled"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "four_year_olds"){
               colour = "Number of 4-Year-Olds Enrolled"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "x3s_4s"){
               colour = "Number of 3- & 4-Year-Olds Enrolled"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "total"){
               colour = "Total Number of Children Enrolled"
             } else if (input$bubble_color == "score"){
               colour = "Number of Quality Standards Benchmarks Met"
             })
```

Comment: You need `labs(colour = if(...)`, once at the start , not `colour =` inside every clause of your if else. That's not how passing arguments works in R.  Try `list(a = if(3 < 4) 1 else 2)` compared to `list(if(3 < 4) a = 1 else a = 2)` to see what's happening.

Comment: *"have not been successful"* hints at an error, a warning, or just nothing at all and the image is wrong. Since we don't have the data, it's rather difficult to infer what's going on. Side note: I suggest breaking out the `if`/then spaghetti code into a separate expression so that you can do just `ggplot(...) + geom_point(..) + labs(colour = my_title)`

Comment: You might also consider `colour = dplyr::case_match(input$bubble_color, "total_spending_from_all_known_sources" ~ "All-Reported Spending", "total_spending_from_all_known_sources_per_child" ~ "All-Reported Spending per Child", ....)`

Comment: And another step you might consider would be to to rename the columns upstream so that the user can select the plain-english names instead of the database names.

Answer (score 0):

Try customizing below template. It takes advantage of {dplyr}'s `pull` verb, which when given two columns, returns a named vector (values from 1st, names from 2nd column) ... handy for the kind of lookups needed to populate select inputs and, in turn, look up the label for a given choice.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput('selectIndicator', label = 'Select indicator:', choices = NULL),
    plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    the_data <- data.frame(indicator_code = c('total_spending_from_all_known_sources_per_child',
                                              'total_state_and_tanf_spending'
                                              ),
                           indicator_label = c('All-Reported Spending per Child', 'State Spending'),
                           year = 2015:2016,
                           value = c(80000, 150000)
                           )

    ## populate the indicator selection with choices:
    updateSelectInput('selectIndicator', session = session,
                      choices = pull(the_data, indicator_code, indicator_label)
                      )

    output$plot <- renderPlot(the_data |>
                              filter(indicator_code == input$selectIndicator) |>
                              ggplot(aes(year, value)) +
                              geom_point(aes(color = input$selectIndicator)) +
                              labs(color = (pull(the_data, indicator_label, indicator_code))
                                   [input$selectIndicator]
                                   )
                              )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```